# Given a shape, return all triangles that can be formed

Tags: java, algorithm, combinatorics

> Given a shape, get all triangles that can be possible by connecting the points.
>
> Example: given 3 points, only 1 triangle is possible, but given a pentagon, 10 are possible.

Also the combination formula is \$\dfrac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}\$.  Does it mean \$O(n!)\$ is the complexity?

Looking for:

1. Code review optimization and best practices.
2. Verifying complexity:

   Time:  \$O\left(\dfrac{n!}{r!  (n-r)!}\right)\$ - which I guess is the same as \$O(n!)\$.

   Space:  \$O\left(\dfrac{n!}{r! (n-r)!} \cdot r\right)\$ - space occupied by the list to be returned.

```
public final class GetTriangles {

    private GetTriangles() {}

    /**
     * Returns the list of all the triangles possible, given the input shape.
     * If the less than three points are returned it causes illegal argument exception
     */
    public static List<int[]> combinate (int n) {
        if (n < 3) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The input shape has less than 3 points:  " + n);
        final List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
            compute(i, new int[3], 0, n, list);
        }
        return list;
    }

    private static void compute(int startFrom, int[] a, int arrPosition, int n, List<int[]> list) {
        if (arrPosition == a.length - 1) {
            a[arrPosition] = startFrom; 
            list.add(Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length));
            return;
        }

        a[arrPosition] = startFrom; 

        for (int i = startFrom + 1; i <= n; i++) {
            compute(i, a, arrPosition + 1, n, list);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
       final List<int[]> list = combinate(5);

       int[] a1  = {1, 2, 3};
       int[] a2  = {1, 2, 4};
       int[] a3  = {1, 2, 5};
       int[] a4  = {1, 3, 4};
       int[] a5  = {1, 3, 5};
       int[] a6  = {1, 4, 5};
       int[] a7  = {2, 3, 4};
       int[] a8  = {2, 3, 5};
       int[] a9  = {2, 4, 5};
       int[] a10 = {3, 4, 5};

       final List<int[]> list1 = Arrays.asList(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10);

       for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
           assertArrayEquals(list.get(i), list1.get(i));
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: *... but given a polygon 10 are possible"* <- makes little sense... what polygon?

Comment: oops - goofed pentagon with polygon. Sorry

Comment: @rolfl implemented optimistic recursion as you suggested in one of previous reviews :) thanks

Comment: I don't think your test is great, because it expects a particular order for the result, and there is nothing in the problem that requires any particular order.

Answer (score 5):

No, it doesn't mean \$O(n!)\$ complexity.  The \$(n-r)\$ in the denominator cancels most of the terms in the numerator.  For choosing three points to make a triangle, \$r\$ = 3, and so your actual expression is \$\frac{(n)(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}\$ => \$\frac{(n^3-3n^2+2n)}{3!}\$ => \$O(n^3)\$.

So you should expect \$O(n^3)\$ time, and \$O(3*n^3)\$ => \$O(n^3)\$ space.

Next thought - if you are going to be working with triangles, you need to know where the points are (so that you can check whether or not the points are co-linear).  What your code currently does is seek out every 3-tuple combination of vertices; so you are (possibly) missing part of the problem.

That said, breaking the triangle problem into two distinct pieces is a good idea; because you do need to enumerate the vertices anyway, and treating them as ordered tuples gives you a good way to avoid extra work.

But trying to enumerate the tuples using recursion... that's a bad idea.  Better would be to simply enumerate the combinations using squashed ordering.  [Thomas Andrews](http://bridge.thomasoandrews.com/impossible/algorithm.html) has a nice illustration of that technique on a more complicated problem.